# ASP.NET MVC 6 FormCollection not being populated in AJAX post

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm upgrading a project to MVC 6 from MVC 5 and have found that the *FormCollection* is not being populated (ie returning a null value) with the data from an AJAX post.

The data is being sent down the wire correctly:

[image: Form post data]

The signature of the method in the controller is:

```
public string processform(FormCollection formCollection)
```

I can set a breakpoint in this method which is hit when the form data is submitted, but the *formCollection* object is null.

Given that this code works just fine in the lower versions of MVC, do we have to do something different in MVC 6 to make it go?

Comment: `FormCollection` should be `IFormCollection` in the controller's method signature.

Answer (score 1):

As per [this](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/issues/186) question:

> FormCollection as a parameter is not supported (yet) by MVC 6

You can do it using these two ways:

1. To read the values async as per this [article](https://dzone.com/articles/aspnet-mvc-6-reading-form)
2. Create your own model binder see [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/commit/088bb18eed498d1b2df96bee52ffbaf744254f61).

Comment: The ways you suggested to me lead me to a better overall answer, so thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

Zaki's post led me down a trail and I ended up with this code that works:

```
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<string> processform()
        {
        var objFormCollection = await HttpContext.Request.ReadFormAsync();
        ...
        }
```

Though with the fast-changing pace of ASP.NET 5/Core 1.0 MVC 6, etc, things may change again.

Answer (score 0):

I read form data and any file attached to the form, which is being submitted, by using HttpContext.
Ex:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void EditProperty()
    {
        var isFeatured = HttpContext.Request.Form["isFeatured"];
        var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(file.FileName);
                System.Console.WriteLine("This file is featured:" + isFeatured.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

In the example above "isFeatured" is a key that I have added to formData using jquery. I hope this was of some help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your input fields have a 'name' attribute.